# Rancher: Adding another Host to Rancher fails on CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: docker, rancher

I have setup a rancher with a host. Now i'm trying to add another host to the same, here is what I did, installed the docker-ce on the new host and then ran the following:

```
sudo docker run --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher 10.10.18.35:5000/rancher/ant http://10.10.18.35:8080/v1/scripts/9F4687F125CF02E0ACF1:1546214400000:L1JlsOJwk5weSux3NHNHNhLWkI
```

I get the following error `(requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590))`:

```
INFO: Running Agent Registration Process, CATTLE_URL=http://10.10.18.35:8080/v1 INFO: Attempting to connect to: http://10.10.18.35:8080/v1 INFO: http://10.10.18.35:8080/v1 is accessible INFO: Inspecting host capabilities INFO: Boot2Docker: false INFO: Host writable: true INFO: Token: xxxxxxxx INFO: Running registration Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./register.py", line 11, in <module>
    secret_key=os.environ['CATTLE_REGISTRATION_SECRET_KEY'])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cattle.py", line 45, in from_env
    return gdapi.from_env(prefix=prefix, factory=Client, **kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdapi.py", line 613, in from_env
    return _from_env(prefix=prefix, factory=factory, **args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdapi.py", line 632, in
_from_env
    return factory(**result)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cattle.py", line 12, in
__init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(*args, **kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdapi.py", line 197, in
__init__
    self._load_schemas()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdapi.py", line 315, in
_load_schemas
    response = self._get_response(self._url)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdapi.py", line 264, in
_get_response
    headers=self._headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Any clues to resolve this please

Answer (score 0):

It is required to access Rancher via ssl.  I see you’re using http instead. To generate a self-signed cert, follow this documentation; https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/single-node-install/#option-a-default-self-signed-certificate